# Kotlin Multiplatform: sharing actual class implementation for multiple targets (iOS, macOS)

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am working on a Kotlin/Native Multiplatform project that supports JVM, iOS, and macOS. My setup has the following modules:

```
- common
- ios
- jvm
- macos
```

I want to use some native code as an `actual` class and put an `expected` class in `common`. However, the actual class implementation is identical for multiple targets (iOS and macOS). Is there a way I can set up my sources (maybe in Gradle) so that I don't have to maintain 2 identical copies of the actual class?

Comment: Can you expand on this "However, the actual class implementation is identical for each target (iOS, JVM, and MacOS)". If they're identical, why are you doing expect/actual? I can see iOS and MacOS being the same, but all three?

Comment: @KevinGalligan edited with clarification. You are correct, iOS and macOS are the same but JVM is different.

Answer (score 5):

Stately has a fairly involved config. iOS and Macos share all of the same code.

To structure the project, there's `commonMain`, `nativeCommonMain` depends on that, and actually `appleMain` which depends on `nativeCommonMain`.

```
commonMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
    }
}

jvmMain {
    dependsOn commonMain
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    }
}

nativeCommonMain {
    dependsOn commonMain
}

appleMain {
    dependsOn nativeCommonMain
}

configure([iosX64Main, iosArm64Main, macosMain, iosArm32Main]) {
    dependsOn appleMain
}
```

That structure is probably deeper than you need, but we needed something for linux and windows that was different. Egor's answer above is easier to follow I think.

We actually define multiplatform atomics in Stately, so you can use them as inspiration or actually just use the library itself.

https://github.com/touchlab/Stately

### Common

```
expect class AtomicInt(initialValue: Int) {
  fun get(): Int
  fun set(newValue: Int)
  fun incrementAndGet(): Int
  fun decrementAndGet(): Int

  fun addAndGet(delta: Int): Int
  fun compareAndSet(expected: Int, new: Int): Boolean
}
```

#### JVM

```
actual typealias AtomicInt = AtomicInteger
```

#### Native

```
actual class AtomicInt actual constructor(initialValue:Int){
  private val atom = AtomicInt(initialValue)

  actual fun get(): Int = atom.value

  actual fun set(newValue: Int) {
    atom.value = newValue
  }

  actual fun incrementAndGet(): Int = atom.addAndGet(1)

  actual fun decrementAndGet(): Int = atom.addAndGet(-1)

  actual fun addAndGet(delta: Int): Int = atom.addAndGet(delta)

  actual fun compareAndSet(expected: Int, new: Int): Boolean = atom.compareAndSet(expected, new)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In [Okio](https://github.com/square/okio), we declare two additional source sets, `nativeMain` and `nativeTest`, and configure the built in native source sets to depend on them:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'

kotlin {
  iosX64()
  iosArm64()
  linuxX64()
  macosX64()
  mingwX64('winX64')
  sourceSets {
    nativeMain {
      dependsOn commonMain
    }
    nativeTest {
      dependsOn commonTest
    }

    configure([iosX64Main, iosArm64Main, linuxX64Main, macosX64Main, winX64Main]) {
      dependsOn nativeMain
    }
    configure([iosX64Test, iosArm64Test, linuxX64Test, macosX64Test, winX64Test]) {
      dependsOn nativeTest
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all three implementations are identical, just put that code in `common`. `expect/actual` is only used for things that are *different* on different platforms

Comment: I originally misspoke. I meant to say the iOS and macOS target implementations are identical. JVM is different. I want to use an atomic integer which I can use [AtomicInt](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native.concurrent/-atomic-int/index.html) for iOS and macOS but need to use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for JVM

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kotlin DSL your build.gradle.kts file might look like this:

```
kotlin {
    android()
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "yourframeworkname"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}
```